# Not able to select paths in SVG picture

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to animate a flower SVG image so that it will look like the flower is drawing itself, as described in [this](http://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/) article. I've included my current code in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ykvawyz/).

I can't seem to access each path element, and I'm not too sure why. I used the Javascript code provided in the article, and I downloaded/included the svg HTML for an SVG flower I found online. When I run the code, the console in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome logs 0, telling me that there are no elements with the tag name path. I'm not sure why this is; can anyone explain why/what I should fix?

Here is the javascript code:

```
var paths = document.getElementsByTagName('path');
console.log(paths.length);
for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    var path = paths[i];
    var length = path.getTotalLength();
    // Clear any previous transition
    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
      'none';
    // Set up the starting positions
    path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
    // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
    // picks up the starting position before animating
    path.getBoundingClientRect();
    // Define our transition
    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
      'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out';
    // Go!
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
}
```

Here is some of my HTML code:

```
<body>
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.0"
   width="800px"
   height="800px"
   id="svg2385">
  <!-- <defs
     id="defs2387" />
  <g
     transform="translate(-163.06366,-372.39925)"
     id="layer1"> -->
    <path
       d="M 368.89962,527.3412 C 359.4568,464.38904 307.36168,439.5961 286.4323,430.39488 C 267.82968,422.21658 263.76952,407.10258 263.76952,407.10258 C 263.76952,407.10258 258.73335,424.09966 258.73335,432.28344 C 258.73335,440.46722 256.84479,478.86804 271.9533,510.97363 C 287.06182,543.07923 333.01689,554.41062 346.23685,570.14866 C 359.4568,585.8867 354.42063,613.58565 354.42063,613.58565 C 354.42063,613.58565 353.79111,591.55239 338.68259,578.33244 C 323.57407,565.11249 286.4323,565.11249 265.65809,527.3412 C 244.88388,489.5699 243.11868,419.10884 261.25144,392.62358 C 270.14221,379.63744 261.94361,399.48194 275.73043,412.13875 C 288.52321,423.88299 327.25144,435.53708 350.01398,458.72335 C 375.97069,485.16325 369.52915,528.60024 368.89962,527.3412 z"
       id="path2395"
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
    <path
       d="M 339.98723,553.05793 C 345.42186,528.07876 345.25711,516.73109 330.15128,500.99047 C 314.74039,484.93195 299.71749,490.29179 282.61153,461.86813 C 291.50944,496.40407 313.58336,493.78902 325.88728,512.78659 C 337.91025,531.35036 338.75504,552.37736 339.98723,553.05793 z"
       id="path3199"
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
```

Comment: give me a fiddle code...we can able to get path

Comment: Sorry, should've clarified.. the "current code" linked to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ykvawyz/

Comment: Your jsfiddle displays 12 for me on Firefox.

Comment: Are the animations working too? I copy-pasted my code back from JSFiddle, and it's still showing 0 in the console for Safari/Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: Of course the animations aren't working! Firefox does not support WebkitTransition.

Comment: Maybe it's because the SVG is already drawn before the Javascript runs. Why don't you just put transition codes into the SVG?

Comment: Shouldn't that work in Safari though? I added in path.style.Transition but it's still giving me 0 in Firefox/Chrome; I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ykvawyz/7/   @RobertLongson

Comment: @HakanAktaş do you mean using the animate tag?

Comment: I meant putting `transition` into `<path>`'s style attribute but I tried it on your JSFiddle, and it didn't work.

Comment: Is there anything else I could try changing? I'm not sure if it's a browser issue or a code issue now, but my browsers are all updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this. Because my Javascript code was loading before my HTML code, it was registering 0 paths. I put the script tag between  and  and it worked.

Comment: I bet FF doesn't roll though, does it?